# Why is this subset not an element of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics by Ralph P. Grimaldi, 5th ed., on Set Theory:

Let U = {1,2,3,4,5,6,x,y, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4}}. Then |U| = 11.

If A = {1,2,3,4}, then |A| = 4 and we have

1) A is a subset of U

2) A is a proper subset of U

3) A is an element of U

4) {A} is a subset of U

5) {A} is a proper subset of U

6) BUT {A} is not an element of U

Why is {A} is not an element of U? Isn't {A}={1,2,3,4} considered an element in U?

Comment: I rechecked, and it's {A}. This is from the Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics by Ralph P. Grimaldi, 5th edition.

Comment: {A} = {{1,2,3,4}} which is not an element of U

Comment: Is $A$ a Quine atom? Are you assuming Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

Now we have $\{1,2,3,4\}\in U$ so all the elements of $\{A\}$ are elements of $U$, which is essentially the definition of $\{A\}\subset U$

But we don't have $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}\in U$ so we don't have $\{A\}\in U$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $\{A\}$ means "the set which has $A$ as its only element". Such a set is a subset of $U$, but not an element. Basically: $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull - there's a difference between the set $\{A\}$, i.e. the set that contains only $A$, and the set $A$.

$\{A\}$ indeed isn't an element of $U$, because $U$ doesn't contains the set $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

But of course $A$ *is* an element of $U$, because $U$ *does* contain the set $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Similarly (and maybe even more confusingly at first sight), the sets $\{\}$, $\{\{\}\}$, $\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$ are all different.

But you have in general that if $x$ is an element of some set $M$, then $\{x\}$ is a subset of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

$\{A\}\ne \{1,2,3,4\}$.  It's actually equal to $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ and $\{A\}\not\in U,$ but $\{A\}\subset U$ since $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}\subset U$

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$
\{A\}=\big\{\{1,2,3,4\}\big\}\ne\{1,2,3,4\},
$$
since 
$$
1\in\{1,2,3,4\},
$$
while
$$
1\not\in\big\{\{1,2,3,4\}\big\}.
$$
Note that
$$
x\in\{\{1,2,3,4\}\} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x=\{1,2,3,4\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\{A\}$ is not $\{1,2,3,4\}$, but you have to put one more pair of braces around it: $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$. This is not an element of $U$.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake in notation. $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, but $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.